# EmberJS Testing always passes

Tags: ember.js, ember-testing

New to EmberJS.  I'm trying to get some testing going.. but having some basic trouble it seems.  I simply generated an acceptance test -- taken straight from the Ember site.

```
import { test } from 'qunit';
import moduleForAcceptance from 'ssd-admin-ember/tests/helpers/module-for-acceptance';

moduleForAcceptance('Acceptance | login');

test('visiting /login', function(assert) {
  visit('/xxxlogin');

  andThen(function() {
    assert.equal(currentURL(), '/abclogin');
  });
});
```

I then run it with:

```
ember test --filter 'acceptance/login-test'
```

This yields...

```
ok 1 PhantomJS 2.1 - JSHint | acceptance/login-test.js: should pass jshint

1..1
# tests 1
# pass  1
# skip  0
# fail  0
# ok
```

How can this possibly pass? There is no xxxlogin route etc.

I must be doing something wrong (clearly).

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You are not running your test. You only run the JSHint checks. And it is ok for that file.

You are not running your test because your filter statement is wrong. It should be:

```
ember test --filter "Acceptance | login"
```

Comment: Actually `filter` parameter filters the output. I said "you are not running your test" but the reality is "you are running your test, but filtering it out"

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the quick response. Now have 2 other issues which are unrelated I assume. 1)  No tests.js in my tests index.html file -- which I just inserted there.. but still complains.. and 2) Could not find module `..../resolver.

Comment: Note: To fix the resolver issue (which was generated code..)

import Resolver from 'ember-resolver';

Comment: You can look at an app's tests. Such as [this ember app](https://github.com/ykaragol/table-test/tree/master/tests).